# JavaScript Promises: conventional way to pass arguments

Tags: javascript, promise

How do i pass additional arguments to next "step" of promise?

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const a = // do stuff and return a string
  return Promise.all([
    // execute another promise,
    // execute yet another promise
  ])
})
.then(([resultFromPromise_1, resultFromPromise_2]) => {
  // how do i pass `const a` here?
})
```

I can add something like `new Promise(resolve => resolve(a))` into `Promise.all` array, but this looks ugly. Is there better way to pass data in such cases?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to achieve? Perhaps a [mcve] with a running example not using `a`, and (as you've done above) a comment showing where you want to and what you want to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

> I can add something like `new Promise(resolve => resolve(a))` into `Promise.all` array, but this looks ugly. Is there better way to pass data in such cases?

Yes: Use `then`. If you already have a promise, using `new Promise` is never needed. `then` creates a promise, which waits for the resolution of the one you called it on, and then gets resolved with what you return from the `then` callback or gets rejected if you throw an exception. One of the keys of promises is how using `then` (and `catch`) *transforms* things at each link in the chain.

In that specific case, you'd use `then` on the original promise and use its callback to transform the result using `a` (although if you want to wait until they're all done, you can do that too; covered later).

Side note: The `new Promise` line at the beginning of the code of your question shouldn't be there, you don't *return* a promise out of the promise executor (the callback you pass to `new Promise`).

Example:

```js
const a = "some string";
Promise.all([
  getPromise("one").then(result => result + " - " + a), // ***
  getPromise("two")
])
.then(results => {
  console.log(results);
});

function getPromise(str) {
  // (Could use Promise.resolve here; emphasizing asynchronousness)
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(str);
    }, 250);
  });
}
```

Alternately, if you really only want to use `a` when all of the promises you're passing to `Promise.all` have resolved, you can do that, too:

```js
const a = "some string";
Promise.all([
  getPromise("one"),
  getPromise("two")
])
.then(([result1, result2]) => {
  return [result1 + " - " + a, result2]; // ***
})
.then(results => {
  console.log(results);
});

function getPromise(str) {
  // (Could use Promise.resolve here; emphasizing asynchronousness)
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(str);
    }, 250);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, your first promise has an error, you're not resolving it. You should do something like this:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const a = 1;
  resolve(Promise.all([
    ...    
 ]))
})
```

And as for your question, instead of `new Promise(resolve => resolve(a))` you can just pass `a` directly to the `all` array. ie:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const a = 1;
  resolve(Promise.all([
    Promise.resolve("a"),
    Promise.resolve("b"),
    a,
  ]))
})
.then(([resultFromPromise_1, resultFromPromise_2, a]) => {
   console.log(a);
})
```

Comment: `new Promise(resolve => { resolve(x); })` is just a long way to write `Promise.resolve(x)`. And in this case, the `x` is `Promise.all(...)`, which already returns a promise, so it's completely pointless. :-)

Comment: Interesting idea to pass `a` in the `Promise.all`. If you're already using `Promise.all`, not a bad idea at all! But it's not a general-purpose solution...

Comment: What do you mean `it's not general-purpose`? Passing the value directly to the `all` array is a way of passing more `arguments` to the `next step`, it is what was asked in this question.

Comment: I just meant if you're dealing with a single promise, not using `Promise.all`. Though I suppose you could always *add* `Promise.all` if you weren't already using it. I think I'd stick with the closure, but again, interesting thought.

Comment: I see, well, if it was a simple promise you could also return just the value to the next step, the promise return could be a new promise or just a value.

Comment: Yeah, that's the general-purpose method I was talking about. Anyway, your passing it through `Promise.all` is pretty directly an answer to this specific scenario, nice one.